# asp.net core how decrease class coupling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, solid-principles

how I can optimize for class coupling?. This is my class and visual studio show class coupling is **16** which is higher the maximum standard **9**.

```
public class Auth:IAuth
    {
        public List<AuthDetail> GetAuths()
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

            var auths = config.GetSection("Auth").GetChildren().ToList()
                .Select(x => new AuthDetail
                {
                    UserName = x.GetValue<string>("UserName"),
                    Source = x.GetValue<string>("Source"),
                    Password = x.GetValue<string>("Password")
                }).ToList();
            return auths;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dIt's hard to tell exactly what it's complaining about out of context, but I'd imagine it's just the level of dependencies your class owns (i.e. things it's creating), and in general, the knowledge it must have about other components. For example, it must know about `ConfigurationBuilder` and how that works. While it has nothing to do with "class coupling", it also needs to know that there's an `appsettings.json` file. You also have some magic strings like your `Auth` section, where this whole thing will fail if the config isn't set up that way. Again, that's not necessarily "class coupling", but it still is a problem.

Personally, I'd throw this entire thing in the trash, at least based on its current state. Maybe the `Auth` class needs to do other stuff as well, but this part is almost entirely useless.

First, your config should be externalized. That's sort of the whole point. I'm assuming this is part of a library, and if so, libraries shouldn't have this kind of knowledge. They should depend on abstractions only, which gives you extensibility.

In your actual ASP.NET Core app is where you should specify configuration (and `appsettings.json` is already included by default). You should also be employing strong-typed config, which can take the place of all this logic here. In other words, this can be replaced with:

```
services.Configure<AuthOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Auth"));
```

And then you would just need the following class:

```
public class AuthOptions
{
    public List<AuthDetail> Auths { get; set; }
}
```

And, you're done. If your `Auth` class *is* doing other stuff, then you can simply inject this `AuthOptions` class into it:

```
public class Auth : IAuth
{
    private readonly List<AuthDetail> _auths;

    public Auth(IOptions<AuthOptions> authOptions)
    {
        _auths = authOptions.Value?.Auths;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, just simply use `_auths` instead of calling `GetAuths`. If you want to expose the "auths" publically (since `GetAuths` was a public method), you can either implement a property with a custom getter, keep `GetAuths` but just have it return `_auths` or just make the `_auths` ivar public.